# How can I calculate the covariance of 2 random variables, given the second one and the variance of the first one?

Tags: variance, covariance

If X is a random variable with variance 1 and $Y = -2X+5$ how do I calculate the covariance of X and Y? I know the formula of the covariance is $cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$, but from the given data, I'm not sure how to use it. Any ideas?

Comment: With variation 1?

Comment: Hint: covariance is linear in both arguments.

Comment: $XY = -2X^2 + 5X$, so compute the expected value of the RHS to get $E[XY]$.

Comment: @Bungo if var(X) = 1 => $E(X^2) - E(X)^2 = 1$, if $XY = -2X^2+5X$, then $E(XY) = -2E(X^2) + 5E(X)$, $E(Y) = -2E(X) + 5$. Is this correct? If so, just like you said, how would I be able to get a result? (I believe I should get one because I'm given the choices: -1, 2, -2, 0, 1

Comment: So far so good. It looks like you need to know $E(X)$, but in fact it will cancel out in the end. Just set it equal to say $\mu$ for now. So $E(XY) = -2(\sigma^2 + \mu^2) + 5\mu$, and $E(Y) = -2\mu + 5$. Now plug these into $E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$. (Here $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $X$, which is $1$ in your case.)

Comment: @Bungo Thank you!! I got -2 as a result

Comment: In general when $Y$ is a linear function of $X$ with gradient $m$ and intercept $c$:$$\tiny\begin{align}\mathsf {Cov}(X,mX+c) &= \mathsf E(mX^2+cX)-\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(mX+c)\\&=m\,\mathsf E(X^2)+c\,\mathsf E(X)-m\mathsf E(X)^2-c\,\mathsf E(X)\\&=m\,\big(\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2\big)\\&=m\,\mathsf {Var}(X)\end{align}$$ So, when the gradient is $-2$ and variance of $X$ is $1$, then the covariance will be $-2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments so this can be marked as resolved..

---

Let $\mu$ denote the unknown mean of $X$, and let $\sigma^2 = 1$ be the variance of $X$.

Observe that $XY = -2X^2 + 5X$, so
$$E(XY) = -2E(X^2) + 5E(X) = -2(\sigma^2 + \mu^2) + 5\mu$$
Also,
$$E(Y) = -2E(X) + 5 = -2\mu + 5$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{aligned}
cov(X,Y) &= E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)\\
&= -2(\sigma^2 + \mu^2) + 5\mu - \mu(-2\mu + 5) \\
&= -2\sigma^2 \\
&= -2
\end{aligned}$$
(The terms involving $\mu$ cancel, so it's not necessary to know its value.)

Answer (score 0):

Since the correlation coefficient $\rho=-1$ and the standard deviation of $Y$ is $\sigma_Y=2$ we have $\sigma_{XY}=\rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y=-2$.